What organs of fish are these?
I found two organs in a fish. I heard the fish us called pacific herring. The two organs are large compared to the fish size. It looks like liver, but pale and large. Some said it is male reproductive organs, maybe fish sperms. What are they? Are they edible?


Your intuition is right, those are the milt, or or milt sacks
They are edible, and fried into a delicacy in some places.

To clarify, below is a photo of a male herring with its milt and a female herring with its ovaries.


https://alaskafish.news/03/2023/huge-herring-fisheries-upcoming-at-sitka-kodiak-togiak/
In commercial fisheries, only the eggs have value. The de-egged carcass and all the males are rendered or discarded.
Edit: Word of warning: Pacific Herring are a different species than an Atlantic Herring (which are used to make Scandahovian pickelled herring). If you try to pickle Pacific Herring, you may find them mushy.

Is such commercial fishery sustainable?

No. I was involved in the herring fishery in the 1970's. Catches were so huge that several sein boats were capsized when the fish in their nets spooked and tried to flee. The fishery collapsed and has never recovered. Herring are the foundation of the food chain for everything up to orcas. Sustainable? Ha !
